# C# equivalent of Event Objects in c++ , winapi

Tags: c#

is there an equivalent in C# of the event objects created in c++ using the win api function "CreateEvent".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is called [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx).
To create a named auto reset event which can be opened by other processes you can use this:

```
bool bCreated;
var ev = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, @"Global\myGlobalEvent", out bCreated);
```

If you want a simple Manual/AutoResetEvent you can use the classes [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) respectively. WaitHandle exposes the full feature set such as creating a named event.

Yours, 
   Alois Kraus

Answer (score 1):

There are various synchronization primitives available in C#/.NET, events are directly available as [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) or [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx), or, more generally, they are wrapped in [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx).